# Moment.js : change the default humanize() behavior

Tags: javascript, momentjs

[In the moment.js documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/) the following example is given:

```
moment.duration(1, "minutes").humanize(); // a minute
moment.duration(2, "minutes").humanize(); // 2 minutes
moment.duration(24, "hours").humanize();  // a day
```

I need to have for this call

```
moment.duration(1, "minutes").humanize();
```

an output "1 minute" and I want to have for this string

```
moment.duration(24, "hours").humanize();
```

an output "24 hours".

I cannot just replace the "a" word with 1 because it is going to be used for many different languages.

Is that possible? Maybe some simple config / workaround / non-documented feature?

Answer (score 10):

From the [moment.js documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/) you can customize it like so:

```
moment.locale('en', {
    relativeTime : {
        future: "in %s",
        past:   "%s ago",
        s:  "seconds",
        m:  "a minute",  //change that to "%d minute"
        mm: "%d minutes",
        h:  "an hour",   //here too
        hh: "%d hours",
        d:  "a day",     //and here
        dd: "%d days",
        M:  "a month",   //and so on...
        MM: "%d months",
        y:  "a year",
        yy: "%d years"
    }
});
```

I know this solution is not perfect, but couldn't find any better.

Answer (score 0):

To have an output "24 hours" from `moment.duration(24, "hours").humanize();` with moment you can use [relative time threshold](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-threshold/) like moment.relativeTimeThreshold('h',25)