# Customize certain momentjs humanized duration values

Tags: momentjs

Short question: I need momentjs to humanize 60 minutes into `1 hour` instead of `an hour`. Can't figure out how to get it to work.

Long question: 
Just started using momentjs, works great. We are using it to display how often a dashboard is updated.

The timers are set as a integer in minutes. We are using the humanize moment option to display `30` as `30 minutes` and `360` as `6 hours` etc.

This works great but not in 2 cases. `60` gets humanized to `an hour`. We need it to be `1 hour`. And `1440` is displayed as `a day`, instead of `1 day`.

We need this change because the column is answering the question "How often does your metric update?"

The answer is "every 1 hour". "every **an** hour" doesn't quite work.

I read through the docs and googled, but couldn't find a way to customize just a few humanized display formats.

We are already setting true as the second parameter to get just the value without the suffix from this question and answer - [How to Customize Humanized Moment js Date Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509618/how-to-customize-humanized-moment-js-date-result)

But the value comes back as 'an hour' instead of '1 hour'.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `updateLocale` method documented in the Customize -> [Relative time](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/) section of the docs. This will affect output of `from`, `fromNow`, `to`, `toNow` and `humanize`.

In your case you can simply update `h` and `d` keys of the `relativeTime` object.

Here a working sample:

```js
moment.updateLocale('en', {
  relativeTime : {
    h: "1 hour",
    d:  "1 day",
  }
});

var d1 = moment.duration(60, 'm');
var d2 = moment.duration(1440, 'm');

console.log(d1.humanize());
console.log(d2.humanize());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

You can find further examples of relative time customization [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31804518/4131048) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38367038/4131048).

Comment: Thanks! Great info.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the methods like `minutes()`, `months()`, `years()` available on the duration object and then you can create your own string. the `humanize()` method gives an approximate value against the duration and not the exact duration.