# Changing duration text in vue-moment

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, momentjs

I'm trying to display an array of numbers

`const days = [1, 7, 14, 30, 60]`

in humanized form via vue-moment

it's working fine

```
{{ days | duration('humanize') }}
// 'a day'
// '7 days'
// '14 days'
// 'a month'
// '2 months'
```

## Problem

I want `1 month` instead of `a month`

How can i change that?
I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31804664/6066886 answer, it implies changing the vue-moment config.

The docs at https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment state that

> vue-moment should respect any global Moment customizations, including i18n locales. For more info, check out http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/.

> You can also pass a custom Moment object through with the plugin options. This technique is especially useful for overcoming the browserify locale bug demonstrated in the docs http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/browserify/

But both of these would force me to install moment AND vue-moment, just to create a moment-config-object to pass into vue-moment.
Or am i missing something?

I'm looking for a way to pass `{M: '1 month'}` in somewhere and be done with it. Isn't that possible?

( loading vue-moment with `Vue.use(require('vue-moment'))`)

Comment: `vue-moment` already pulls in `moment` (you'll see `moment` in `node_modules` after installing `vue-moment`), so technically you're not adding a new dependency.

Comment: oh wow. and it makes total sense too :D thanks!

Comment: and it's working just fine! can you post it as an answer? <3

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

`vue-moment` already pulls in moment (you'll see `moment` in `node_modules` after installing `vue-moment`), so technically you're not adding a new dependency.